# python get sql server last inserted id fails

Tags: python, sql-server

In SQL management studio.
I can first

```
insert into MyTable(Data) Values('test')
```

Then do

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY as ID
```

and get the correct ID result, which means my SQL server is running right.

In python, I tried to do the same through pypyodbc to get the last inserted id, first use

```
sql_server_insert('insert into MyTable(Data) Values('test')')
```

second use

```
result = sql_server_select('select max(ID) as ID from MyTable')
```

I do get the correct result ID just inserted, which means both my insert and select code works.

But if I use

```
result = sql_server_select('SELECT @@IDENTITY as ID')
```

or

```
result = sql_server_select('select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as ID').
```

what returned back is a 'None' in the result.

No exception in the sql execution. Where might be the mistake? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest using the `OUTPUT` clause.  That is the recommended way to return the new ids.

Comment: Looks like you've wrapped pypyodbc in your own functions.  Furthermore, unless you have a hidden global variable (or are not showing actual code) it looks like the two statements may be executing in different connections.  Try ensuring that they both execute in the same connection.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. OUTPUT works great. I did not know this before.

Comment: Thanks Larry. You pointed to the exact reason, I need to do this in the same connection.